# How do I select only hidden rows in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel 2013 spreadsheet with 4000 rows. Sprinkled throughout it are a dozen or so rows that have been hidden (by highlighting them, right clicking and selecting "hide").

How can I select just those hidden rows?  I want to select them so that I can change their formatting (and not the visible row's formatting) or so I can delete just the hidden rows.

Here is the closest solution I've found.  Say I want to make the rows red.

- select all
- turn everything red
- use Home->Find and Select->Go To Special->Visible cells only, so only the visibile cells remain selected
- turn the visible cells white again

That method doesn't let me delete them, and doesn't handle the case where there's a mixture of formatting the visible cells, so I'm looking for a better option

Comment: To delete only hidden cells, I'd suggest copying the visible cells to a new sheet and deleting the old sheet.  I don't think you can select hidden cells only.

Comment: You must hid the hidden rows first in Excel. You could write a vb script, but that would be unnecessary for this solution -- like spinning a house to unscrew a light bulb so you don't have to twist your wrist.